# Number of combinations to the nth step taking 1, 2 or 3 steps at a time‽

Tags: java, function, math, int, combinations

I am doing the following programming exercise: [Number of combinations to the nth step](https://www.codewars.com/kata/5da82e8712f2c6001eebc5d2). The statement is:

> You need to get to the nth stair, the challenge is to get the number
>   of different ways you can get to the nth stair with taking 1,2 or 3
>   steps at a time.
>
> So for exmaple how many ways to get to the 3rd step. You can get there
>   4 was as shown here: [1,1,1] [1,2] [2,1] [3]
>
> Write the method findCombs that finds all the different combinations
>   of ways you can reach the nth step!

Until now, I have calculated by hand the combinations:

```
1 -> [1]

2 -> [1,1], [2]

3 -> [1,1,1], [1,2], [2,1], [3]

4 -> [1,1,1,1],[2,1,1][1,2,1],[1,1,2],[2,2],[3,1],[1,3]

5 -> [1,1,1,1,1],[2,1,1,1],[1,2,1,1],[1,1,2,1],[1,1,1,2],[2,2,1],[2,1,2],[1,2,2],[3,2],[2,3]

6 -> [1,1,1,1,1,1],[2,1,1,1,1],[1,2,1,1,1],[1,1,2,1,1],[1,1,1,2,1],[1,1,1,1,2],[2,2,1,1],[2,1,2,1],[2,1,1,2],[1,2,2,1],[1,1,2,2],[2,2,2],[3,2,1],[2,3,1],[1,2,3],[3,3]
```

If it is correct we have the following combinations for each number of steps:

```
1: 1; 2: 2; 3: 4; 4: 7; 5: 10; 6: 16...
```

So far I have written, that if the number of steps is 0 or negative, it should output -1; if steps are 1 or 2, we count 1 or 2 respectively.

```
public class Stairs {
    public int findCombs(int n){
      if(n <= 0) return -1;
      if(n <= 2) return n;
      return 0;
    }
}
```

Being the tests:

```
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;

public class mainTests {

    @Test
    public void test_n_3(){
        Stairs stairs = new Stairs();
        Assert.assertEquals(4,stairs.findCombs(3));
    }

    @Test
    public void test_n_7(){
        Stairs stairs = new Stairs();
        Assert.assertEquals(44,stairs.findCombs(7));
    }

    @Test
    public void test_n_25(){
        Stairs stairs = new Stairs();
        Assert.assertEquals(2555757,stairs.findCombs(25));
    }

    @Test
    public void test_n_0(){
        Stairs stairs = new Stairs();
        Assert.assertEquals(-1,stairs.findCombs(0));
    }
}
```

How could we calculate the general case?

I have read:

- [How to generate the power-set of a given List?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20935315/how-to-generate-the-power-set-of-a-given-list)
- [Generate All Possible Combinations - Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37835286/generate-all-possible-combinations-java)
- https://www.superprof.es/apuntes/escolar/matematicas/probabilidades/combinatoria/combinaciones.html
- [Java program to calculate the combinations function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19532553/java-program-to-calculate-the-combinations-function)

So then, how could we calculate the number of combinations to the nth step taking 1, 2 or 3 steps at a time‽

EDIT: Following @Saurav Kumar Singh answer, I wrote the following:

```
public class Stairs {
    public int findCombs/**/(int n){
      if(n <= 0) return -1;
      if(n <= 2) return n;
      if(n == 3) return 4;
      return findCombs(n-1) + findCombs(n-2) + findCombs(n-3);
    }
}
```

And it passes the tests. However I would like to remove the hard coded base case:

```
if(n == 3) return 4;
```

I tried:

```
public class Stairs {
    public int findCombs(int n){
      if(n <= 0) return -1;
      if(n <= 2) return n;
      return findCombs(n-1) + findCombs(n-2) + n-3 > 0 ? findCombs(n-3) : 1;
    }
}
```

However it outputs -1 when we want to have the stairs for 3, 1 for 4, 2 for 5...

I also tried:

```
public class Stairs {
    public int findCombs(int n){
      if(n <= 0) return 1;
      if(n <= 2) return n;
      return findCombs(n-1) + findCombs(n-2) + findCombs(n-3);
    }
}
```

However when n is negative or 0, it outputs 1, instead of -1

How could be program the solution without the need to include: `if(n == 3) return 4;`‽

Comment: This can be solved using **dynamic programming** !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can be solved easily using **Dynamic Programming.**

if you have solved till **Nth step** then to reach **N+1th** step will be either of this -

- Possible ways to reach **Nth** step + **single** step to N+1th step
- Possible ways to reach **N-1th** step + **double** step to N+1th step
- Possible ways to reach **N-2th** step + **tripple** step to N+1th step

Hence `S(N+1) = S(N) + S(N-1) + S(N-2)`